# ESP8266: Externalizing multiplexer logic produces errors

Tags: c++, microcontroller, esp8266, i2c

I have an I2C multiplexer connected to my ESP8266 and attached five SH1106 OLED displays to it (bus 2 to 6). I tested everything with simple example code and it works. I have then written the following code in which I try to externalize the display switch logic to an own class and make it more handy to use. It compiles and loads onto the board, but I keep getting errors and only one of the display infrequently flickers the word "TEST". Do you have any idea why?

main.cpp :

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <services/displayservice/DisplayService_h>

#include "SH1106Wire.h"

DisplayService displayService;

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
    for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
       SH1106Wire display = displayService.display(i);
       delay(2000);
       display.clear();
       display.flipScreenVertically();
       display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_24);
       display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER);
       display.drawString(64, 20, String("TEST"));
       display.display();
       delay(500);
    }
}
```

With my own class DisplayService:

DisplayService_h :

```
#ifndef DisplayService_h
#define DisplayService_h
#include "SH1106Wire.h"
class DisplayService {
   public:
    DisplayService();
    SH1106Wire display(u_int8_t displayNumber);
   private:
    void changeDisplay(u_int8_t displayNumber);
};
#endif
```

DisplayService.cpp :

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SH1106Wire.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include "DisplayService_h"

SH1106Wire displayObject(0x3C, SDA, SCL);  // ADDRESS, SDA, SCL

DisplayService::DisplayService() {}

SH1106Wire DisplayService::display(u_int8_t displayNumber){
    Serial.println(displayNumber);
    this->changeDisplay(displayNumber);
    displayObject.init();
    return displayObject;
}

void DisplayService::changeDisplay(u_int8_t displayNumber){
    Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);  // TCA9548A address
    Wire.write(1 << displayNumber); // send byte to select bus
    Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

"Error message" if you can call it that :

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,7)

load 0x4010f000, len 3460, room 16
tail 4
chksum 0xcc
load 0x3fff20b8, len 40, room 4
tail 4
chksum 0xc9
csum 0xc9
v00046240
~ld
```

Comment: If nothing else you probably don’t want to init the displays in `loop`; they should be initialized only in `setup`. You can create an array/list of displays and operate on those in `loop`.

Comment: You can’t call it an error message; it’s not one. It’s the standard output from the ESP8266 when it boots. You can however google “rst cause:2” to get a guess t what caused the reboot and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason, but I found a solution: Instead of passing the display object around, I now pass only a pointer to the display.

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SH1106Wire.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include "DisplayService_h"

SH1106Wire aDisplay(0x3C, SDA, SCL); // ADDRESS, SDA, SCL

DisplayService::DisplayService() {
}

SH1106Wire* DisplayService::display(u_int8_t displayNumber){
    this->changeDisplay(displayNumber);
    aDisplay.init();
    return &aDisplay;
}

void DisplayService::changeDisplay(u_int8_t displayNumber){
    Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);  // TCA9548A address
    Wire.write(1 << displayNumber);          // send byte to select bus
    Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

However, it wouldn't work if I wouldn't init the display each time I change the active display.